# Does Oracle database hold history of previous database versions

Tags: oracle, versioning

I need to know if there is a way of querying within Oracle database to find out how the database versions have changed over time e.g. when my organisation shifted from Oracle 12C to Oracle 19C and so on.
I am looking for this information within Oracle before I start digging into procurement records etc as I need this for a document writing about how our database has changed and grown over time.

I know I can receive the current version from v$version, but if Oracle holds history of when previous versions were installed, that would be really helpful.

Thanks

Sean

Comment: [DBA_REGISTRY_HISTORY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DBA_REGISTRY_HISTORY.html)
`SELECT * FROM   dba_registry_history WHERE action = 'UPGRADE'`

Comment: Also check for DBA_REGISTRY_SQLPATCH - `SELECT patch_id, version, status, bundle_id, bundle_series FROM dba_registry_sqlpatch;`